# Cant figure out how to properly pull keys from config

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft, bukkit

I've been trying to implement a config file for a very basic EntityDeathEvent script in order to allow for a reload command to be implemented to be able to add to my config and reload the file rather than restarting the server. The current code I'm using returns zero errors so I'm quite lost at this point. I'm 5 days into tinkering with Java so there are probably a bajillion things missing from my code but this is what i have so far.

main.java:

```java
package com.mk7smp.LukesMobEffects;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.ConfigurationSection;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;



public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

  @Override
  public void onEnable() {
    this.saveDefaultConfig();
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisable() {

  }

  public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("mobeffects")) {
      if (!sender.hasPermission("mobeffects.reload")) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Nope, big admin guys only.");
        return true;
      }
      if (args.length == 0) {
        // /mobeffects
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&f[&bmk7 Mob Effects&f] &aUsage: /mobeffects reload"));
        return true;
      }
      if (args.length > 0) {
        // /mobeffects reload
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("reload")) {
          for (String msg: this.getConfig().getStringList("reload.message")) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',
              msg));
          }
          this.reloadConfig();
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @EventHandler
  public void mobDeath(EntityDeathEvent event) {

    Entity entity = event.getEntity();
    Player player = event.getEntity().getKiller();

    if (player == null) {
      return;
    }

    ConfigurationSection mobs = this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("mobs"); // The "mobs" section of the config file

    for (String mobKey: mobs.getKeys(false)) { // For ONE(one bc getKeys is set to true) mob key in the set
      String mobname = (String) mobs.get(mobKey + ".name"); // use specified path to retrieve name value
      String message = (String) mobs.get(mobKey + ".message");
      if (entity.getType().toString() == mobname) {
        for (String effectString: mobs.getStringList(mobKey + ".effects")) {


          //make sure there are no whitespaces in the "effectString"
          String[] values = effectString.split(",");

          //create PotionEffectType
          PotionEffectType type;
          //set default duration to 30 seconds
          int duration = 30;
          //set default strength to 1
          int strength = 1;

          //get type
          type = PotionEffectType.getByName(values[0].toUpperCase());

          //check, if type is null
          if (type == null) {
            System.err.println(effectString + " could not be interpreted into a correct PotionEffectType.");
            continue;
          }

          //set duration
          if (values.length > 1)
            duration = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);

          //set strength
          if (values.length > 2)
            strength = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);

          //check, if player already has potiontype
          if (player.hasPotionEffect(type))
            player.removePotionEffect(type);

          //create the effect
          PotionEffect effect = type.createEffect(duration * 20, strength);
          player.addPotionEffect(effect);
          player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // THESE ARE THE FUNCTIONS THAT I WANT TO USE WITH DATA FROM CONFIG
  //if (entity.getType().toString() == "RABBIT") {
  //    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&f[&bmk7 Mob Effects&f] &aYou've been given &c&lLeaping: 15s &afor killing a &crabbit&a!"));
  //    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.JUMP, 300, 2));
  //    }
  //if (entity.getType().toString() == "ENDERMAN") {
  //    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&f[&bmk7 Mob Effects&f] &aYou've been given &c&lRegeneration: 10s &afor killing a &cenderman&a!"));
  //    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 200, 2));
  //}
  //if (entity.getType().toString() == "CHICKEN") {
  //    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&f[&bmk7 Mob Effects&f] &aYou've been given &c&lFeather Falling: 10s &afor killing a &c&lchicken&a!"));
  //    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SLOW_FALLING, 200, 1));
  //}
};
```

config.yml

```yaml
reload:
   message:
      - "&f[&bmk7 Mob Effects&f] &a&lReloaded config!"
      
mobs:
  rabbit:
    name: rabbit
    message: "&f[&bmk7 Mob Effects&f] &aYou've been given &c&lLeaping: 15s &afor killing a &crabbit&a!"
    effects: 
      - JUMP,15,2
```

please could I just have a hand in the right direction

Comment: I suggest you to use `mobs.getString()` instead of `mobs.get`

Answer (score 0):

Please make the rabbit in line 7 a string. Add quotation marks.

```
reload:
   message:
      - "&f[&bmk7 Mob Effects&f] &a&lReloaded config!"
      
mobs:
  rabbit:
    name: "rabbit"
    message: "&f[&bmk7 Mob Effects&f] &aYou've been given &c&lLeaping: 15s &afor killing a &crabbit&a!"
    effects: 
      - JUMP,15,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have deleted the old config file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).